# local variable 'Body' referenced before assignment- error being thrown up in code however cannot see the reason as 'Body' is defined

Tags: python, python-3.x, nft

This code is throwing up 'local variable 'Body' referenced before assignment' error which is being flagged on the 'for x in body'. I have looked at the code and I am really struggling to find the cause of the error as the issue isn't consistent with the other conditions I have created using the same format?

```
    bgs = ['01_BG_Blue.png', '02_BG_Red.png', '03_BG_Green.png', '04_BG_Grey.png', 
    '05_BG_Orange.png', '06_BG_Silver.png', '07_BG_Navy.png', '08_BG_Cave.png', '09_BG_Forest 
    Background.png']
    Body = ['01_Body_Wolf.png', '02_Body_Green Wolf.png','03_Body_Ice Wolf.png']
    Outfit = ['00_Outfit_Fighter.png', '01_Outfit_Spartan.png', '02_Outfit_Black belt 
    Fighter.png']
    Weapons = ['00_Weapons_Sword 1.png', '01_Weapons_Axe.png' '02_Weapons_Quiver.png' 
    '03_Weapons_Sword 2.png' '04_Weapons_Axe 2.png']
    mouths = ['01_Mouth_Tongue.png', '02_Mouth_Snarl.png']
    eyez = ['00_Eyes_Brown eyes.png', '01_Eyes_Grey Eyes.png', '02_Eyes_Red Eyes.png', 
    '03_Eyes_White Eyes.png', '04_Eyes_Snake Eyes.png', '05_Eyes_Future Eyes.png']
    Traits = ['00_Traits_Earring 1.png', '01_Traits_Earring 2.png', '02_Traits_Laural.png', 
    '03_Traits_Pipe.png', '04_Traits_Scar.png', '05_Traits_Crown.png']
    Fweapons = ['00_Overhead_Bow.png', '01_Overhead_Spear.png']
    def gen():
    count = 0
    while count != 5555: # size of collection, so script stops
        traits = []
        traits_names = []
        """
        Just some checks to avoid issues coming up in the big lists of traits.
        """
        for x in backgroundsList:
            if len(x) < 2:
            backgroundsList.remove(x)
        for x in BodyList:
            if len(x) < 2:
                BodyList.remove(x)
        for x in outfitList:
            if len(x) < 2:
                outfitList.remove(x)
        for x in WeaponsList:
            if len(x) < 2:
                WeaponsList.remove(x)
        for x in mouthsList:
            if len(x) < 2:
                mouthsList.remove(x)
        for x in eyesList:
            if len(x) < 2:
                eyesList.remove(x)
        for x in TraitsList:
            if len(x) < 2:
                TraitsList.remove(x)
        for x in FrontweaponsList:
            if len(x) < 2:
                FrontweaponsList.remove(x)
            
        """
        Collecting of the randomly chosen traits.
        """
        bgcheck = random.choice(backgroundsList)
        backgroundsList.remove(bgcheck)
        for x in bgs:
            if x.split('.png')[0].replace('_', ' ').replace(' ', '_', 2).split('_')[2] == 
bgcheck:
                bg = x
                break
        Bodycheck = random.choice(BodyList)
        BodyList.remove(Bodycheck)
        for x in Body:
            if x.split('.png')[0].replace('_', ' ').replace(' ', '_', 2).split('_')[2] == 
Bodycheck:
                Body = x
                break**
```

Answer (score 0):

You've declared all the lists and variables in the global scope(outside the function). So they cannot be accessed from within the function unless you declare them as global variables.

Just add this line at the beginning of the function `gen`:

```
global bgs,Body,Outfit,eyez....
```

Add all the variable names that you want to use in the function.